# Input tag javascript event on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype

The `input` event doesn't work on mobile devices although it works on desktop. Also, I have tried touchend but no results. What I need is to catch a `change` event on a input box on mobile devices. `change` event is working on dropdown but not on input tag.

Here is my code.

```
jQuery(document).on('input touchstart touchend change', element, function(){
   var val = this.value
   //do things;
});
```

Can someone help?

Comment: Just a simple [change](https://jsfiddle.net/go0xhy56/) event works for me.Environment: jQuery 3.2.0 - iPhone SE (Safari). Does your `element` contain the expected value?

Comment: yes, the element contain the expected value. change event isn't working - testing on a iPhone 7 Safari.  however, i need an event similar to keyup maybe, rather than change.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you aren't binding the change event in the right way, this works on mobile too:

```js
$("#inp").change(function(){
  alert($("#inp").val());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="inp" type="text"/>
```

Comment: I would assume OP uses the event-delegation for a reason. Omitting this ans just recommending a different event-handler doesn't sound like a viable solution to me